# Using a method in a Lambda Expression - HTMLDoc

Tags: c#, lambda, html-agility-pack

I want to load **content** into a htmlDocument list using HTML Agility pack.

I have successfully achieved what I want using:

```
        var htmllist = new List<HtmlDocument>();



        int counter = 0;

        foreach(var c in content)
        {

            htmllist.Add(new HtmlDocument());
            htmllist[counter].LoadHtml(c);
            counter += 1;
        }
```

How can i write this in a Lambda expression? I tried:

```
 var htmllist = content.Select(p => new HtmlDocument() {Text = p })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `ToList()` to execute the query like

```
var htmllist = content.Select(p => new HtmlDocument() { Text = p }).ToList();
```

Per your comment and another comment: you can change your existing code a bit like

```
private HtmlDocument LoadHtmlFromContent(string content)
{
  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml(content);
  return doc;
}
```

Now call this in your Linq query like

```
var htmllist = content.Select(p => this.LoadHtmlFromContent(p)).ToList();
```

Comment: Is { Text = p } equivalent to LoadHTML(content) ?

Comment: @user8608110 not sure about that

Comment: @Rahul: It is not. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/oFK6Yf
Not calling `LoadHtml()` leads to properties being null. This answer doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.Select`accepts an arbitrary selector as `Func<TSource,TResult>`. So you can inline the conversion method, but imho it really doesn't look great…

```
content.Select(c => {var doc = new HtmlDocument(); doc.LoadHtml(c); return doc;});
```

If you're using C# >=7.0 you could think about using a [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) for that. E.g.

```
void Convert(IEnumerable<string> content)
{
    var htmls = content.Select(ConvertToHtml);

    HtmlDocument ConvertToHtml(string c)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(c);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

That looks more maintainable to me.